# Pass the anchor text of a Jquery generated link from another server into a Jquery var

Tags: javascript, jquery

Not sure this is possible but maybe you can help.

I have a list, where the content of the `<li>`'s is generated by Javascript, through a function called `showLink();` this ***function is on another server and it's not controlled by me***.

The `showLink();` function generates a **html link**. I am interested in the generated anchor text.

**QUESTION: Is there a way I can use Jquery to get the anchor text of that link into a Jquery variable?**

Here is the code:

```
<ul class="my_list">
<? $zero = '0';
   for($rn = 1; $rn <= $traffic_rows_nr; $rn++){ ?>
       <li><script language="JavaScript">showLink(<? echo $rn; ?>)</script></li>
<? } ?>
</ul>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
var anchorText = $("ul.my_list li a").text();
```

or...

```
var anchorText = [];
$("ul.my_list li a").each(function() {
    anchorText.push($(this).text());
})
// anchorText is now an array of the text in all the anchors in the list
```

Answer (score 0):

`var text = $(".my_list a").text();` Should do it